# Base table or view not found Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

I have a migration

```
    /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('a_delivery_pec_delivery_ranges', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('weight');
        $table->float('volume');
        $table->float('length');
    });

    Schema::table('a_delivery_pec_delivery_ranges', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->index('weight', 'weight_index');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{

    Schema::table('a_delivery_pec_pickup_coef', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropIndex('weight_index');
    });

    Schema::dropIfExists('a_delivery_pec_delivery_ranges');
}
```

when i try in console "php artisan migrate" or "php artisan migrate:refresh --seed" or "php artisan server" or "php artisan migrate:rollback" or "composer dump-autoload" i catch error

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'delivery_update.a_delivery_pec_delivery_ranges' doesn't exist

Comment: The error may be from a different migration file. Do a search for `delivery_update`.

Comment: delivery_update only in my .env file

Comment: ohhh, i can`t run php artisan. And my application are not working. Problem in Connection.php file

Comment: Then it sounds like you're not connecting to the correct database.